# How to build a transparent double hollow helix at home

Tags: plastic, molding

I'm building a product prototype for a client. We are trying to figure out the best way to build a hollow helix capable of transporting liquid at home. Something similar to this:

[image]

So far our best idea is to use standard tubing and try to use rings mounted on the side of a support cylinder which the helix loops through but this seems almost impossible to pull off at a small scale, and wouldn't look too good.

We have also considered heating sand and using that to bend acrylic tubing, but this certainly still doesn't feel ideal.

Comment: The diameter of your tube stock will affect the minimum bend radius you'll be able to make.  We need more information.  Also, see the "tour" page: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Can you provide some details as to **why** you need this helical approach?  heat transfer, total volume, or  pure aesthetics?   There might be a better design from a functionality point of view.

Comment: If this is a relatively low-pressure setup,  consider using a stock 3D extrusion printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Buy, or make two metal springs of desired helix diameter and pitch; wire diameter considerably narrower than the desired helix.
2. Coat the springs in paraffin, immersing in molten paraffin, possibly a couple times, until coated spring diameter is as desired.
3. Twist the two springs together to create the double helix.
4. Place the helix in a tube (either openable length-wise cast, or something easily destructible, say, thin plastic or glass. Fix it in place so that it won't move
5. Pour clear acrylic resin to fill the tube; leave it to cure.
6. Remove the item from the tube cast.
7. Heat gently, to melt the paraffin, but not to damage the resin.
8. Screw the springs out of the canals.
9. Wash the surplus paraffin out with warm ethanol.

For actual production process (after prototyping) consider extruding pure paraffin or other easy to melt material into the desired form dual helix, without wire core (use extruder similar to one used to make pasta).

Comment: +1 A very clever method and within the realm of the garage hobbyist.  And you can re-use the molding parts. Good stuff.

Comment: Might it be difficult to get a large volume of clear acrylic to set in a consistent manner throughout its length?  I can't help thinking it would look cloudy in places.

Comment: @Wossname: Not getting any bubbles, and getting an even coating of paraffin (no droplets hanging below) will likely be more tricky. Still, the general idea is to have two kinds of hardening/softening process; thermal and chemical. Fill using one process, remove helical "fill" using the other - so e.g. you might make the "springs" from something that is heat-resistant but soluble in something that won't damage the plastic, and e.g. use hot plastic (or even glass?) to fill the space. Say, make zinc springs, pour glass, immerse in acid to dissolve the springs.

Comment: Generally, scale models / miniature / diorama makers have good tips on use of resins, including clear resins. I saw some beautiful landscape dioramas with rivers made from clear resin; no clouding problems but the process of making was considerably more tricky than just "mix and pour".

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the tube around a shaft then release it (it will grow slightly). You can find many youtube videos describing this process using a drill or lathe to do this for metal springs. The process for a tube is/is nearly identical. Your tube material just has to be suitably deformable to hold the shape like this.

Comment: for a prototype you might even wrap around a transparent tube and leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the diameter you want, but the scaffolding wheels can be adjusted for height and the "screw" is quite coarse - that may give you a "nice" profile to work with... heat and gloves spring to mind...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you finished your project,but if you didn't have to see the liquid, I would use copper tubing. I would carefully wrap two tubes on a dowel of the right diameter (it will reduce a little in diameter when you stretch them) and after removing the dowel stretch the coils appropriately. It should be self supporting but you could wrap solid bare wire 16 - 10 AWG around each coil (assuming 3/16" - 3/8" diameter tubing) from the bottom to the top of the helix in 3 or more evenly spaced supports. If sagging is still a problem you can work springs over the support wires, but be aware there may be galvanic corrosion from the dissimilar metals, and you may want to dip the springs in liquid electrical tape or spray them in insulator paint MIL-E-22118.
If you need to see the liquid I would use clear vinyl tubing supported with self adhesive cable clips sized appropriately with 4 or more evenly spaced wood or plastic supports.